# How to display message sender's image with app icon image for push notification of an iOS messaging app

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm trying to develop push notification UI of a messaging app.
Like I desire, some messaging apps updated their message push notification with the sender's image on the left (not on the right side like an attached image).
So it seems possible, and maybe by iOS UserNotification Kit or UIKit.

Plus, I guess app icon image could be combined as a small size on the right bottom corner of sender's profile image. Just like iMessage push notification.

How can I display sender's profile image on push notification for a messaging app?

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications) is Apple's comprehensive guide on how to add custom UI to user notifications on iOS.

In a nutshell, you need to:

1. Add a Notification Content Extension
2. Configure UI there
3. Connect UI with provided notification view controller (this is where you parse your notification payload before showing it to the user)
4. Add a notification category to the notification (if not yet) and configure the extension to include this category

Comment: Can you please provide some code? I couldn’t find any tutorials for that... I've only found guides for an image on the right of the banner!

Comment: @SotirisKaniras Using Notification Content Extension, you can build almost any UI for your notifications. Here's one of plenty tutorials can be found on internet: https://chicio.medium.com/rich-ios-notifications-with-notification-content-app-extension-be1ed1ade200.